# Simple explanation about checking whether a line segment intersects a sphere or a cube

Tags: java, math, game-engine, raycasting

I'm currently working on a raycaster, but I have one single problem.
Everything is set up, now I just need a bit mathematical help to answer following questions, and I couldn't find any simple explanation and we haven't learned such advanced vector stuff in school yet.

**1]** I have a line going from, lets say, (0,0,0) to (50,50,50)
now how can I find out if its intersects with a sphere, e.g (m = (10,10,5), r = 5)?
Yes, I searched around the whole internet, but ANYTHING is explained in vectors, but since they are not the same as lines that go from A to B, I never found anything helpful.

**2]** I have the same line from above, but this time I want to check if it intersects with a Cube, m = (25,30,50), it has a sidelenght of 5 units.
As before, please keep your explanation as simple as possible, an I'm working with Java by the way.

Comment: If you go to coursera there are free courses on linear algebra.

Comment: google for `infinite line to point distance` if it is smaller or equal then `r` you hit the sphere ...  or solve: `p=p0+(p1-p0)*t AND (p.x-sx)^2 + (p.y-sy)^2 + (p.z-sz)^2 <= r^2` where `p0,p1` are your line points, `sx,sy,sz` is your sphere center and `r` its radius. `t` is parameter. `p=(p.x,p.y,p.z)` is point on line with parameter `t`

Comment: what is the parameter t used for?

Comment: @dani_a_cruel_killer: Look up equations of lines in three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Sphere**: The idea is to find the distance from the sphere's center to the line. If it is greater than the radius --> outside, vise versa - inside ( and if equal --> on the surface)

The equation of a line which goes through 2 point A, B is

```
x = A.x + (B.x - A.x)*t
y = A.y + (B.y - A.y)*t
z = A.z + (B.z - A.z)*t
```

The distance from the point M to a point in the line AB is:

```
d(t) = Math.sqrt((x - M.x) * (x - M.x) + (y - M.y) * (y - M.y) + (z - M.z) * (z - M.z))
```

The distance from the point M to the line AB is the shortest d(t)

If we set

```
g(t) = (x - M.x) * (x - M.x) + (y - M.y) * (y - M.y) + (z - M.z) * (z - M.z)
```

We will have

```
d(t) = Math.sqrt(g(t))
```

To find `min(d(t))`, we will try to find `min(g(t))` instead (because the function derivative will be simpler). And to find `min(g(t))`, solve the equation `derivative(g(t)) = 0`

You will find

```
t = ((B.x - A.x)*(M.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y)*(M.y - A.y) + 
(B.z - A.z)*(M.z - A.z))/((B.x - A.x)*(B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y)*(B.y - A.y) + (B.z - A.z)*(B.z - A.z))
```

Then you can find d (or d*d)

2) **Cube**: The idea is to find the intersection of the line (AB) with each side of the cube and see if at least 1 side has the intersection inside the square

You don't say anything about whether the cube have sides parallel with coordinate axes, but let's use that case (the simplest :) )

The AB line's equation is the same as in 1)

```
x = A.x + (B.x - A.x)*t
y = A.y + (B.y - A.y)*t
z = A.z + (B.z - A.z)*t
```

The equations of all 8 sides are: (in your example, d = 5)

```
X = M.x - d
X = M.x + d
Y = M.y - d
Y = M.y + d
Z = M.z - d
Z = M.z + d
```

You should find the intersection between AB with each side of the cube
For example, AB with X = M.x -d

Solve the system of equations:

```
x = A.x + (B.x - A.x)*t
y = A.y + (B.y - A.y)*t
z = A.z + (B.z - A.z)*t
x = M.x - d
```

You will find:

```
x = M.x -d
t = (M.x -d - A.x)/(B.x - A.x) .. then find y, z
```

The point (x,y,z) is inside the side X = M.x -d of the cube if

```
M.y - d <= y <= M.y + d (and similar for z)
```

And do the same for other sides.

**NOTE**: If you want to check whether the segment [AB] intersects (reaches) the sphere/cube, you need to check one more conditions: The intersection is in the segment [AB]

```
min(A.x, B.x) <= x <= max(A.x, B.x)
min(A.y, B.y) <= y <= max(A.y, B.y)
..
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Thank you very, very much for this comment!

Comment: And yes, it helped me:D

Comment: May i ask what "when d = mininum (d(t))" means?

Comment: I have updated my answer to be clearer. Please check!